# Two MySQL queries giving different results

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I have these two queries that I'm running. The first one works, but for some reason the EXISTS() function seems to add about a minute of load time, which makes it unbearable to use. So I wrote a second query that I feel should give the same answer, but it gives a very differt answer instead.

**First**

```
select 
count(`FavoritesHeaderID`) `count` 
from `favoritesheader` 
join `vwactiveevent` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`favoritesheader`.`MainEventID` 
where `Admin`=0 
and exists(
select 1 
from `invoiceheader` 
join `vwactiveevent` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`invoiceheader`.`MainEventID` 
where `Phone`=`favoritesheader`.`CellPhone` 
and `OrderStatusID`=2
); => 284
```

**Second**

```
select 
count(`FavoritesHeaderID`) `count`
from `favoritesheader` 
join `vwactiveevent` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`favoritesheader`.`MainEventID`
join  `invoiceheader` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`invoiceheader`.`MainEventID` 
where `Admin`=0 
and `Phone`=`favoritesheader`.`CellPhone` 
and `OrderStatusID`=2; => 1578
```

I don't know if just this is enough information to go off of, but if it is then any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's different about the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the `JOIN` is including duplicated rows in your `COUNT`.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, assuming `FavoritesHeaderID` is unique and that's the field you're trying to `COUNT`, you can add `DISTINCT` to each query and they should return the same count:

```
select 
    count(distinct `FavoritesHeaderID`) `count`
from `favoritesheader` 
    join `vwactiveevent` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`favoritesheader`.`MainEventID`
    join  `invoiceheader` on `vwactiveevent`.`MainEventID`=`invoiceheader`.`MainEventID` 
where `Admin`=0 
    and `Phone`=`favoritesheader`.`CellPhone` 
    and `OrderStatusID`=2
```

Comment: You definitely know your stuff, especially when I first posted this, I was missing information in the question. Thanks

Comment: @stumpx -- np, glad I could help!